# DLL load failed for pytables

Tags: python-3.x, pytables, hdfstore

I get the following error when running code containing pytables:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pierr\python354\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 469, in __init__
import tables  # noqa
File "C:\Users\pierr\python354\lib\site-packages\tables\__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
from .utilsextension import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

...
 File "C:\Users\pierr\python354\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 472, in __init__
'importing'.format(ex=str(ex)))
ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." problem importing
```

python version 3.5.4 |
tables version 3.4.2 | windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. When I tried to run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_hdf('some.hdf')
```

I got an error:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'tables'.  Use pip or conda to install tables.
```

Even though the `pytables` module was installed using both conda and pip (with last, of course as `tables`), the error still persisted.
The `import tables` didn't work either:

```
from .utilsextension import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

`"Не найден указанный модуль"` means `"The specified module was not found"` in Russian.
I climbed into the folder where the last module from the Traceback is located - '~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Lib\site-packages\tables' and found file named `utilsextension.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` there. Then I downloaded `Dependency Walker` utility and looked at this file. The program said it couldn't find `pytables_hdf5.dll`. I found this file in the folder `~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Lib\site-packages\tables\` and added it to a PATH variable by:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.expanduser('~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\tables')
```

After that everything worked, `import tables` and `pd.read_hdf` return no more errors.
Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: Nice tool the dependency walker is, but when I used it (for the same problem of ImportError at .utilsextension), it said it cannot find several files, including python37.dll and zlib.dll. I suppose it is missing some path somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Installing PyTables using [these installation instructions](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html) helped me to resolve this issue. I used Conda option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It went away after I uninstalled and reinstalled pytables.

```
conda remove -n MYENVNAME pytables
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pytables
```